# What is this format of function called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function animator(shapes, $timeout) {
    (function tick() {
        var i;
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var maxX      = 600;
        var maxY      = 600;
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        $timeout(tick, 30);
    })(); // What is this for?
}
```

Here I don't understand the functionality. I am new to this kind of script. Inside of the main function is like ()(). What is this for?

Comment: I think it's called a self invoking function...A function that is defined and immediately executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [iife - What is the (function () {})() construct in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1168892)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-invoking function as @lix pointed out.

> Function expressions can be made "self-invoking".
>
> A self-invoking expression is invoked (started) automatically, without being called.
>
> Function expressions will execute automatically if the expression is followed by ().

Answer (score 7):

This is an IIFE, Immediately-invoked function expression.

[Why use an IIFE?](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#iife)

> Why?: An IIFE removes variables from the global scope. This helps
>   prevent variables and function declarations from living longer than
>   expected in the global scope, which also helps avoid variable
>   collisions.
>
> Why?: When your code is minified and bundled into a single file for
>   deployment to a production server, you could have collisions of
>   variables and many global variables. An IIFE protects you against both
>   of these by providing variable scope for each file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it has a separate name, it's just immediately executed.

Instead of `function a(){..}; a()` you can do `(function(){..})()`

Useful for scoping the vars inside, while placing/executing it right where you want it, also you don't have to invent a name for it.

Answer (score 2):

`(function(){console.log('test')})()` will call function immediately. So if you will write this statement then it will be called immediately and prints test on console.